# Is there some "free-able" memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, free

```
int main()
{
    char *s1, *sTemp;

    s1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*7);
    *(s1 + 0) = 'a';
    *(s1 + 1) = 'b';
    *(s1 + 2) = 'c';
    *(s1 + 3) = 'd';
    *(s1 + 4) = 'e';
    *(s1 + 5) = 'f';
    *(s1 + 6) = '\0';

    sTemp = (s1 + 3);

    free(sTemp); // shud delete d onwards. But it doesn't !!

    return 0;
}
```

Hello,

In the **C** above code `sTemp` should point to the 3rd cell beyond `s1` ( occupied by 'd')
So on calling `free(sTemp)` i expect to have ***something*** deleted from this location onwards.

( I purposely mention '***something***' as the motive of my experiment initially was to find out till which location the free() ing works )

However i recieve a `SIGABRT` at the `free()`.

How does `free()` know that this is not the start of the chunk. and correspondingly can we free up memory only from start of chunks? [ are they only the free-able pointers that `free()` can accept?? ]

Looking forward to replies :)

Comment: This is c code and has nothing to do with c++. Removed the tag

Comment: S.K.: read section 4 of [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/) (and section 6, and ...). You will like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the man pages

> `free()` frees the memory space pointed
>   to by `ptr`, which must have been
>   returned by a previous call to
>   `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.
>   Otherwise, or if `free(ptr)` has already
>   been called before, undefined
>   behaviour occurs.

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/3/free

Answer (score 3):

About the actual question "how does `free` know...":

`free` knows that it is not at the start of the chunk because it maintains metadata that you don't know about. If you think about it, that's *necessarily* so, because otherwise it could never know how much memory to free, given only an address.

It is not specified how exactly the runtime keeps book of allocation sizes, only that you must *never* pass any pointer to `free` that did *not* come from a function of the `malloc` family.

Usually this works by `malloc` allocating a little more memory than needed<sup>[1]</sup> and writing some metadata in memory *preceding* the address that is returned. `free` then just looks at e.g. `ptr[-8]` or whatever (implementation detail!) to read this metadata.
It can then optionally do some consistency checks, and can determine the size of the memory block (one trivial consistency check that is probably always done is checking proper alignment of the pointer).

Having mentioned that, please please please, don't even think about playing with this metadata.

<sup>[1]</sup> It often does that anyway to satisfy alignment requirements and because of allocator internals (most allocators manage memory in different "buckets" of fixed size), so if you allocate, say, 4 bytes, you *nominally* get 4 bytes, but the runtime really allocated 8 or 16 bytes most of the time (without you knowing).

Answer (score 2):

You can only `free()` pointers that were actually `malloc`ed (or `calloc`ed, `realloc`ed). If you try to free only a portion of memory by passing in a different pointer (even one that is "part" of another pointer), the C runtime will not be pleased (as you can see.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot free the memory because free doesn't know how much memory to free.Your program has information about the address malloc() returned and not for every address in this space.So you can free(s1) but not free(s1+3).Also you can handle your pointers as an array in this example:
s1[0]='a';

Answer (score 1):

You can only `free()` memory that was previously `malloc`ed, `calloc`ed, or `realloc`ed, as dlev and Daniel have said.

The reason for this is implementation-dependent, but involves the method of keeping track of allocated memory.

Efficient memory allocation is a difficult problem because different memory allocation algorithms work well depending upon how memory is allocated: a few small chunks, half of which are freed, then slightly larger blocks being grabbed, etc.

The objective is to keep the size of the memory block used by the program at a minimum (usually this chunk will be a continuous block of virtual memory), while keeping the usage of the space within that block extremely high (few gaps between used segments of memory).

Remember that these blocks can't be moved except when being `realloc`ed, so there's always going to be some wasted space.

To minimize the waste, metadata about (at least) the size of the block is stored just before it. The memory allocator can look through the used blocks when determining how to handle a new request. If you pick a random memory location, whether part of a previously-allocated region or no, this metadata will not be present and `free` will be unable to determine what should be freed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot free that pointer the way you are doing, check this question and its answer: [Memory Clobbering Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571455/memory-clobbering-error/6571493#6571493)