# Memory Clobbered

Tags: c, memory, char

I am puzzled by this response.Can anyone help me on this and point out where I am making a mistake? The output at codepad is "`memory clobbered before allocated block`"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    s = "heel";
    printf("%s\n",s);
    printf("%c\n",s[2]);
    printf("%p\n",s);
    printf("%d\n",s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571455/memory-clobbering-error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're trying to free constant memory with:

```
free(s); // cannot free constant "heel"
```

What you're doing is allocating a piece of memory and storing its location (`char *s`).  You are then overwriting that reference with one to a string constant "heel" (memory leak), which cannot be `free`d. To make this behave as desired, you should be copying the constant string to the memory you allocated:

```
strcpy(s, "heel");
```

---

Here is an example for getting user input:

```
char *input = malloc(sizeof(char) * 16); // enough space for 15 characters + '\0'
fgets(input, 16, stdin);

// do something with input

free(input);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. So what it means is using malloc to initialize memory then and s = "heel" are 2 different things? Does s="heel" automatically initialize memory?

Comment: @kevin:  When your program is started, the string constant "heel" is stored in memory and is read-only; `s = "heel"` assigns `s` to the location of that read-only string. So when you're trying to `free(s)` you'd get an error.

Comment: so what happens if I want to input a string from the keyboard and free the memory after I am done with it?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @TimCooper's answer:

- first you do: `char *s = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));`
- then: `s = "heel";`

The first line allocates memory and assigns the location of that memory to `s`. But the second line reassigns `s` to the memory location of constant string `heel` on the stack!

Which means you try and free() memory on the stack, which is illegal. **AND** you leak memory, since what you first allocated to `s` is now inaccessible.

If you want to write a string into the memory pointed by `s`, you should use something like `strcpy()` (or, better, `strncpy()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
char *s = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
  s = "heel";
```

Doesn't do what you think, or what you would expect with more modern languages

The first line allocates some memory for 10chars and returns the address of it.

The second line changes that address to point to a constant block of memory allocated at compile time, containing "heel" losing the link to the allocated memory - leaking it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `free(s)` - it's constant memory.

Try to change `s = "heel";` with `strcpy(s,"heel");`